# Multi-mode Fock states

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, wavefunction

I would like to ask if this expression makes sense.
$$|Ψ⟩ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{7}}(|1000000⟩+|0100000⟩+|0010000⟩+|0001000⟩+|0000100⟩+|0000010⟩+|0000001⟩)$$

For example, $|1000000⟩$ represents one particle in the first mode. Can I interpret $|\Psi\rangle$ as a wave function of one particle?

Comment: What do the individual states in your superposition mean? For example, what does $|1000000\rangle$ represent?

Comment: |1000000⟩ represents one particle in the first mode.

Comment: OK. I'm not sure why you only have 7 modes, but assuming the system does indeed only have 7 modes, then what you have written is a state in the 1-particle subspace of the full Fock space. Therefore the state describes on particle, but the mode of the particle is unknown.

Comment: Shawn Carol says: " if you have a bunch of different modes and all of them are in are in their n equals one state (all of them are supposed to be one particle) that´s just a complicated wave function for a single particle it acts exactly like that". Did I represent his idea correctly? Thanks

Comment: Yes that sounds right and also sounds like what you wrote after you explained what the symbols meant.

Comment: More general one-particle wave function is: $|Ψ⟩ = c_1|1000000⟩+c_2|0100000⟩+...$ and the *complex* parameters $c_i$ depend on the expected energy of $ |Ψ⟩ $ and the energy level of each of the 7 modes.

Comment: Can you give me a formula for calculating the complex parameters ci?